# magento base url for root category

Tags: url-rewriting, categories, magento-1.7, product, base-url

I have several windows in one shop. How can I make Magento use Base URL of Magento settings? Now it duplicates the same item for all windows even if the shop is attached to the catalogue’s root directory.
It means that one item exists on different domains but it placed in the same category of the catalogue

subdomain1/nokia1280
...
subdomain3/nokia1280

URL Rewrite Management does not help

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the question is but if you want to use multible domains with products you should do the following:

**Foreach subdomain**

- Redirect the subdomain to the magento shop ( vhost alias for example )
- Change the .htaccess to set the environment based on Referer
- Add a new Root category for this domain
- Create a new Store with Storeview
- Go to Sysem => Configuration => Web and select the storeview top left
- Change the base URLS to the subdomain for this store.
- Go to System => Configuration => Design and change the template / skin / layout for this store

Now will your subdomain be loaded within his own environment, with his own template and skin.

**More information**

*Use websites*

> Notice that users will be shared along the different domains. If you
>   don`t want this you should go a level further and make more websites.

*.htaccess set environment*

> SetEnvIf Host sub1.website.dev MAGE_RUN_CODE=subdomain1
>
> SetEnvIf Host sub1.website.dev MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
>
> SetEnvIf Host sub2.website.dev MAGE_RUN_CODE=subdomain2
>
> SetEnvIf Host sub2.website.dev MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store

Hope this will help !

Good luck.